# The most efficient way of storing data

Tags: javascript, memory, optimization

Assuming that we need to store some data, what would be the best way to do it, in terms of **speed** and **memory** efficiency?

1: As two different variables

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
```

2: As an array

```
var arr = [1, 2];
```

3: As an object

```
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
```

Comment: As far as I know, memory representation is not covered by the spec, so it's probably implementation-dependent. Also, *speed* of what? Assigning a value? Retrieving a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, it depends on what you are trying to do... Speed and efficiency are more about how you need to manipulate your data than how it is stored.

Just by itself, though, I would expect individual variables to be fastest and smallest.

A quick test (using Node.js and [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage)) shows this to be the case:

`vars.js`: 1080 bytes used

```
var start = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;

( function() {
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;

        console.log( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - start );
} )();
```

`array.js`: 1224 bytes used

```
var start = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;

( function() {
        var a = [ 1, 2 ];

        console.log( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - start );
} )();
```

`object.js`: 1856 bytes used

```
var start = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;

( function() {
        var a = { a: 1, b: 2 };

        console.log( process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - start );
} )();
```

**Note** - this does **not** mean that just declaring two variables takes 1080 bytes!  You are also getting all of the overhead from declaring an anonymous function and running it - this is just a relative measurement.  I wrote the scripts this way so that the variables would not be allocated until after the first measurement is taken.